# "Could not initialize Direct3d"

Tags: directx, directx-11, directx-9

I am trying to run an exe from this Directx-11 tutorial website:[tutorial5](http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut05.html) (exe at the end of the page), but I get the error **"Could not initialize Direct3d"**.

I get the same error when I download the solution and run it on Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2010.

- I have installed the latest DirectX (installed using "DirectX
  End-User Runtime Web Installer":
  [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35))
- I also installed DirectX 9 SDK from here: [DirectX 9 SDK June
  2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812)
- dxdiag shows Direct3d "Enabled".
- I updated the "Intel HD Graphics library on core i5" to the latest driver.

What am I missing? How can I run Directx-11 applications on my machine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error happened here, you should check the result of Initialize function to see what's the error.

```
// Initialize the Direct3D object.
result = m_D3D->Initialize(screenWidth, screenHeight, VSYNC_ENABLED, hwnd, FULL_SCREEN, SCREEN_DEPTH, SCREEN_NEAR);
if(!result)
{
    MessageBox(hwnd, L"Could not initialize Direct3D.", L"Error", MB_OK);
    return false;
}
```

Another useful tip is to turn on DEBUG mode when create device and swap chain. Try the following code the enable debug mode when creating device(in d3dclass.cpp, add the following code before calling D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain, and don't forget to set the third parameter of this function to flags)

```
    UINT flags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;

#if defined( DEBUG ) || defined( _DEBUG )
    flags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif 

// Create the swap chain, Direct3D device, and Direct3D device context.
    result = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, flags, 0, &featureLevel, 1, 
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &m_swapChain, &m_device, NULL, &m_deviceContext);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Build and run the program in debug mode and see the output in VS's output window.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I will try this and see what VS says.

Comment: Hi, I tried turning on DEBUG, and set the fourth parameter to flags just as you suggested. The result is returned as false in both places. ScreenWidth=1280, screenHeight=800. This is what I see in the output window(last 2 lines):
'Engine.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Download Manager\idmmkb.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file

Comment: You should set flags as the third parameter.

Comment: When I make it the 3rd arg, I get the error: "Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast". The prototype of the function is HRESULT WINAPI D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(IDXGIAdapter* pAdapter, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE DriverType, HMODULE Software, UINT Flags, (FeatureLevels) CONST D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL* pFeatureLevels, UINT FeatureLevels, UINT SDKVersion, CONST DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC* pSwapChainDesc, IDXGISwapChain** ppSwapChain, ID3D11Device** ppDevice, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL* pFeatureLevel, ID3D11DeviceContext** ppImmediateContext );

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint at this function and do a step by step debug to see the output from Visual Studio's output window?

Comment: I couldnt step into the function D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain. However, it returned the value -2005270524 to result. Even though I am in Debug mode, the only thing I see in the output window is (last 3 lines)'Engine.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'
'Engine.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'
'Engine.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51957/discussion-between-zdd-and-recursion1212)

Comment: Please give a screenshot of your VS 2013's output window, I want to take a look.

Comment: I'v no idea now, it seems the debug layer not functional, In debug session, can you put your mouse over the variable "result" to see the error string?

Comment: error string doesnt appear, I get only an error code I think or some random negative value.